# Django Model form not rendering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Im trying to create a model form on django but it doesnt want to render even though I mapped it properly and created the path.

models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.

 Media_Choices = (
     ("TV", "TV"),
     ("Radio", "Radio"),
     ("Youtube", "Youtube"),
     ("Podcast", "Podcast"),
  )

class Appear(models.Model):
Show = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Media = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices=Media_Choices)
Episode = models.IntegerField()
Date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
Time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
Producer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Producer_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Show + ' ' + self.Producer_Email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Appear

class AppsForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Appear
         fields = '__all__'

def clean_Producer_Email(self):
    Producer_Email = self.cleaned_data.get('Producer_Email')
    if (Producer_Email == ""):
        raise forms.ValidationError('field cannot be left empty')

    for instance in Appear.objects.all():
        if instance.Producer_Email == Producer_Email:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please fill in correct email')
    return Producer_Emailenter
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import AppsForm

# Create your views here.

def AppS(request):
form = AppsForm()
context = {'forms': form}
return render(request, 'AppsForm.html', context)
```

it refuse to render but it displays the html tag that is in the file but not the fields from the form. this is the html template

AppsForm.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form action="" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|crispy }}

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How are you rendering the form in your template? You've named the form "forms" in your context, is this just a spelling mistake?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you view is wrong try this

```
def AppS(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AppsForm()
    return render(request, 'AppsForm.html', {'form': form})
```

and in your html

```
<form method="POST" class="" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|crispy }} 
  <input type="submit" class="" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

now you are good to go and tell me if you still get error

Comment: @HoustonKhanyile please accept the anwser if it's worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your AppS() function, where you are passing the form as 'forms' to your AppsForm.html you can render it with crispy_forms like:

AppsForm.html:

```
{% extends 'your_app/base.html' %}
    
{% block content %}
    
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
    
<form method="POST" class="" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ forms|crispy }} 
  <input type="submit" class="" value="Submit"> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/